# Record a web page

Tags: javascript, html, snapshot

How can I create some javascript that I can run on my website and leave running overnight that will take a specific URL, and take a snapshot of display it as IMG src. It takes this snapshot of (an iFrame I'm assuming) every 15 minutes after refreshing the iframe and adds the snap shot to an IMG src in a table. It will keep doing this as long as the page is open.

I know nothing of Javascript. /:

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots/6678156#6678156

Comment: You want to save a snapshot in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in JavaScript you will need Node.js.

For the capturing of the web page as image use `phantomjs`.

Comment: Actually, it seems to be possible with pure JS with no support from server: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: I'm familiar with this project but it don't provide you the same quality as phantomjs, since phantomjs runs headless browser which allows you to capture the webpage's state as it is.